# Find the speed of download for a progressbar

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, download, urllib

I'm writing a script to download videos from a website. I've added a report hook to get download progress. So, far it shows the percentage and size of the downloaded data. I thought it'd be interesting to add download speed and eta.
Problem is, if I use a simple `speed = chunk_size/time` the speeds shown are accurate enough but jump around like crazy. So, I've used the history of time taken to download individual chunks. Something like, `speed = chunk_size*n/sum(n_time_history)`.
Now it shows a stable download speed, but it is most certainly wrong because its value is in a few bits/s, while the downloaded file visibly grows at a faster pace.
Can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here's my code.

```
def dlProgress(count, blockSize, totalSize):
    global init_count
    global time_history
    try:
        time_history.append(time.monotonic())
    except NameError:
        time_history = [time.monotonic()]
    try:
        init_count
    except NameError:
        init_count = count
    percent = count*blockSize*100/totalSize
    dl, dlu = unitsize(count*blockSize)             #returns size in kB, MB, GB, etc.
    tdl, tdlu = unitsize(totalSize)
    count -= init_count                             #because continuation of partial downloads is supported
    if count > 0:
        n = 5                                       #length of time history to consider
        _count = n if count > n else count
        time_history = time_history[-_count:]
        time_diff = [i-j for i,j in zip(time_history[1:],time_history[:-1])]
        speed = blockSize*_count / sum(time_diff)
    else: speed = 0
    n = int(percent//4)
    try:
        eta = format_time((totalSize-blockSize*(count+1))//speed)
    except:
        eta = '>1 day'
    speed, speedu = unitsize(speed, True)           #returns speed in B/s, kB/s, MB/s, etc.
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + percent + "% |" + "#"*n + " "*(25-n) + "| " + dl + dlu  + "/" + tdl + tdlu + speed + speedu + eta)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

> **Edit:**
>   Corrected the logic. Download speed shown is now much better.
>   As I increase the length of history used to calculate the speed, the stability increases but sudden changes in speed (if download stops, etc.) aren't shown.
>    How do I make it stable, yet sensitive to large changes?

I realize the question is now more math oriented, but it'd be great if somebody could help me out or point me in the right direction.
Also, please do tell me if there's a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: how about `p=30` and `speed = chunk_size*n/sum(n_time_history) if n<p else chunk_size*p/sum(n_time_history[-p:])` or w/e else you'd like `p` to be

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota Isn't that the same as what I've done in my code?

Comment: my bad, was just looking at logic you described. Since you already doing that, even better estimate can be reached by grouping timeframes (i.e. 0-30,30-60,60-90 or w/e interval you like) and then stripping lowest/highest average values from that set, and calcualting approx time without those extremes. Or use any other statistical filtering method instead min/max. Edit: to make it sensitive to recent changes introduce some weighting which is decreasing over time.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think of weighting. As for the rest of what you suggested, my math is too bad to make sense of it, but I'll look into them all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_count = n if count > n else count
time_history = time_history[-_count:]
time_weights = list(range(1,len(time_history))) #just a simple linear weights
time_diff = [(i-j)*k for i,j in zip(time_history[1:], time_history[:-1],time_weights)]
speed = blockSize*(sum(time_weights)) / sum(time_diff)
```

To make it more stable and not react when download spikes up or down you could add this as well:

```
_count = n if count > n else count
time_history = time_history[-_count:]
time_history.remove(min(time_history))
time_history.remove(max(time_history))
time_weights = list(range(1, len(time_history))) #just a simple linear weights
time_diff = [(i-j)*k for i,j in zip(time_history[1:], time_history[:-1],time_weights)]
speed = blockSize*(sum(time_weights)) / sum(time_diff)
```

This will remove highest and lowest spike in `time_history` which will make number displayed more stable. If you want to be picky, you probably could generate weights before removal, and then filter mapped values using `time_diff.index(min(time_diff))`.

Also using non-linear function (like `sqrt()`) for weights generation will give you better results. Oh and as I said in comments: adding statistical methods to filter times should be marginally better, but I suspect it's not worth overhead it would add.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it out when I get the time. Btw, there's an error in your code. It should be `time_diff = [(i-j)*k for i,j,k in zip(time_history[1:], time_history[:-1],time_weights)]` instead of  `time_diff = [(i-j)*time_weights[i] for i,j in zip(time_history[1:], time_history[:-1])]`. Cuz the values in `time_history` aren't exactly index values for `time_weights`.

Comment: And `speed = blockSize*sum(time_weights) / sum(time_diff)` if my math is right

Comment: haha you are obviously right, shouldn't write answers when I have so much on my head, but this seemed like fun. I'm too used to `i`,`j`,`k` being indexes and avoiding those for actual objects.